# Sorting the dropdown list

Tags: java, jsp

I have a select dropdown list in my JSP. I am populating it from a database using a stored procedure. On the same page I am having another dropdown generated using same stored procedure but the fields are different. The thing is I want to sort the second dropdown in ascending order, according to alphabets. But since the stored procedure can return in only one sort order. The other is populating unordered. Is there any way that I can sort the other dropdown without disturbing the 1st one.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, where:

- `list` is a `java.util.List` containing the values for your dropdown.
- `comparator` is an implementation of `java.util.Comparator` which implements your sorting logic. If your objects are `String`, they are already `Comparable` so you can skip that argument
- this code is placed right after you obtain the information from the stored proc.

Comment: Thanks @Bozho, Since i am new to this can you provide me a little more detail in this. here is my code { <select name="ticker">
                                <%
                                 while (rs.next()) {
                                %>
                                <option value="<%= rs.getString("id_imnt_agg") %>"><%= rs.getString("bbticker") %>
                                </option>
                                <%
                                    }
                rs.close();
                                %>
                            </select>}

Comment: you have to first create a `List` based on your `ResultSet`

Comment: Thanks I created it with Hashmap...With list I was not able to get the values for the select list. Any way thanks